# Create geometry (f.e. LineString()) from stored points. MySQL spatial

Tags: mysql, spatial, spatial-query, mysql-spatial

Is there any way to create some Geometry (f.e. `LineString(pt1,pt2,...)`) from MySQL query (where `pt1,pt2,...` is a result of another query, in other words `pt1,pt2,...` stored in MySQL table)?

Example: `SELECT LineString(SELECT point FROM points) AS line;`
Thanks!

Comment: What version of MySQL are you asking about? This feature is there now?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to append points to LINESTRING SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45799208/how-to-append-points-to-linestring-sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem and solved it in this way:

```
SELECT pt1, pt2, pt3, pt4, @Line_string := GEOMFROMTEXT(CONCAT('LINESTRING(',pt1,' ',pt2,', ',pt3,' ',pt4,')')) FROM table;
```

Answer (score 1):

## `LineString(pt1,pt2)`

[MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-mysql-specific-functions.html#function_linestring) and [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/linestring/) both support this now with `LineString(pt1,pt2,...)`

```
> SELECT ST_AsText( LineString( Point(0,0), Point(1,1) ) );
+---------------------------------------------------+
| ST_AsText( LineString( Point(0,0), Point(1,1) ) ) |
+---------------------------------------------------+
| LINESTRING(0 0,1 1)                               |
+---------------------------------------------------+
```