# How to append points to LINESTRING SQL

Tags: mysql, geometry, append, vertices

I have a table with `points` which is a LINESTRING. I have a row in there which has some points in said column.

I have a second set of points in the form a of a string, I would like to append these points to the existing row. Is there any way to do this in MySQL without selecting the points as text, manually merging the strings then updating `points` in the row?

Comment: When you say you have a second set of points in the form of a string? what do you mean? In what form is that string? Can you make a `ST_Point()`?

Comment: Say I am tracking my position on a cycle ride and sending the lat/lng to a server

The server keeps a LINESTRING representing my route up to the current point

I would like to add a point every few seconds as I travel, to reflect my route

Obviously as the LINESTRING grows in size, it gets increasingly inefficient to convert it to text, add a point, then convert back to spatial data

I was wondering if there was a function to efficiently append a point directly to the end of the LINESTRING. I hope that makes sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MYSQL Spatial function does not include any solution for appending a LINESTRING but there is a workaround which i have tried for you.

1. Get the value

   set @gval = (select ST_AsText(route) from `spatial` where id =5);

> *I named the table as 'spatial' and added a column as 'route' which is of datatype linestring*

2. Appended the string by using the replace function and entering your required lat lon (or point)

   set @gval = replace(@gval, ')', ',8.5684875 76.8520767)');
   Update `spatial` set route =GEOMFROMTEXT(@gval) where id=5;

this works good for me.

Answer (score 0):

> Say I am tracking my position on a cycle ride and sending the lat/lng to a server The server keeps a LINESTRING representing my route up to the current point I would like to add a point every few seconds as I travel, to reflect my route Obviously as the LINESTRING grows in size, it gets increasingly inefficient to convert it to text, add a point, then convert back to spatial data I was wondering if there was a function to efficiently append a point directly to the end of the LINESTRING. I hope that makes sense?

In this case, normally you would

1. Create a new row with each new data point. That new row should have time, and your `POINT`.
2. Then you would create a view (or materialized view) that aggregated those rows of points into a `LINESTRING`. To do that, see [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/227638/2639).

In MySQL and PostgreSQL you don't really want to do append to a `LINESTRING` for every point insertion. In MVCC databases, usually `UPDATE`ing a row requires rewriting the *entire* row. For some cases it may not matter at all, but if you're writing 100+ point routes I wouldn't go that method.

*ℹ In PostGIS this is slightly easier as you have **spatial aggregates** that aren't available to you in MySQL, like [`ST_MakeLine`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeLine.html). So you can do `SELECT ST_MakeLine(pt ORDER BY pointTime) FROM table GROUP BY bike_route;`. You also have functions like [`ST_AddPoint`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AddPoint.html) which adds a `POINT` to a `LINESTRING` (in the event your routes are short or you don't care about write-heavy updates).*